# Detecting and adjusting for negative zero

Tags: c++, algorithm, negative-number

I have some code that has been port from Java to C++

```
// since this point is a vector from (0,0,0), we can just take the
// dot product and compare
double r = point.dot(normal);
return (r>=0.0);
```

But in C++ `r` can be either `+0.0` or `-0.0`, when `r` equals `-0.0` it fails the check.

I've tried to adjust for negative zero in the code below but it never hits the DEBUG("Negative zero") line. But `r2` does print out equal to `+0.0`.

```
// since this point is a vector from (0,0,0), we can just take the
// dot product and compare
double r = point.dot(normal);
if (std::signbit(r)){
    double r2 = r*-1;
    DEBUG("r=%f r=%f", r,r2);
    if (r2==0.0) {
        DEBUG("Negative zero");
        r = 0.0; //Handle negative zero
    }
}
return (r>=0.0);
```

Any suggestion?

TESTING CODE:

```
DEBUG("point=%s", point.toString().c_str());
DEBUG("normal=%s", normal->toString().c_str());
double r = point.dot(normal);
DEBUG("r=%f", r);
bool b = (r>=0.0);
DEBUG("b=%u", b);
```

TESTING RESULTS:

```
DEBUG - point=Vector3D[ x=1,y=0,z=0 ]
DEBUG - normal=Vector3D[ x=0,y=-0.0348995,z=0.0348782 ]
DEBUG - r=0.000000
DEBUG - b=1
DEBUG - point=Vector3D[ x=1,y=0,z=0 ]
DEBUG - normal=Vector3D[ x=-2.78269e-07,y=0.0174577,z=-0.0174391 ]
DEBUG - r=-0.000000
DEBUG - b=0
```

GCC:

```
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ 
--prefix=/usr 
--program-suffix=-4.6 
--enable-shared 
--enable-linker-build-id 
--with-system-zlib 
--libexecdir=/usr/lib 
--without-included-gettext 
--enable-threads=posix 
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 
--libdir=/usr/lib 
--enable-nls 
--with-sysroot=/ 
--enable-clocale=gnu 
--enable-libstdcxx-debug 
--enable-libstdcxx-time=yes 
--enable-gnu-unique-object 
--enable-plugin 
--enable-objc-gc 
--disable-werror 
--with-arch-32=i686 
--with-tune=generic 
--enable-checking=release 
--build=x86_64-linux-gnu 
--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

FLAGS:

```
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -fPIC
```

ANSWER:

I've used @amit's answer to do the following.

```
return (r>=(0.0-std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()));
```

Which seems to work.

Comment: the behavior is non-standard. what compiler and floating point math options are you using. i suspect g++ with fastmath

Comment: also, please post a complete and not-too-large example that exhibits the problem, with complete build instructions so that it is *reproducable*

Comment: thanks. as it turns out (see my answer) it was only the described behavior, about "negative zero" comparing unequal to zero, that was non-standard. in reality there is apparently no negative zero, just a very small negative value, which with the given output format is *presented* as all zero digits with a minus sign in front.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf and hth Yea, that was the problem. I've used std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() to help adjust for that problem.

Comment: oh I forgot to mention: since the "problem" was only in the *perception* of what went on, it is by far most likely the the best course of action would be to *do nothing* (except possibly about the presentation). by comparing with epsilon and nulling, you have possibly introduced a bug. which, ironically, might *look* like correct behavior when evaluated in the context of the erroneous perception.

Comment: The accepted answer and your `r>(0.0-std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())` does nothing to differentiate between `-0` and `0`; both are less than epsilon. The values that underflow to `-0` (if flow-to-zero/denormals-are-zero flags are set) lie between `0` and epsilon.

Comment: If you want to detect positive or zero r values, then you should not test -0.0 to true, as it's a negative number. It's only too small to be represented with a non zero mantissa but still it's negative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, a generic suggestion when using `double`s is remembering they are not exact. Thus, if equality is important - using some tolerance factor is usually advised.

In your case:

```
if (|r - 0.0| >= EPSILON)
```

where `EPSILON` is your tolerance factor, will yield true if `r` is not 0.0, with at least `EPSILON` interval.

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping for a more general solution. This may be the best approach, I'll have to keep looking.

Comment: Change my question to include an answer

Comment: Although correct and notable, this does not answer the question as asked as it does not distinguish between `0.0` and `-0.0`; they're equal to each other and both would be less than epsilon.

Comment: @RJFalconer Thank you, I somehow missed an absolute value, that should be there. (fixed). Also note, that for `r==0.0` and `r== -0.0`, `r < 0.0 - EPSILON` (assuming positive EPSILON, of course).

Comment: I don't think that's right. For `r==-0.0`, `r > 0.0 - EPSILON`. Even the smallest epsilon (`std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon`) is less than `-0.0`.

Comment: @RJFalconer I was giving the "find not equal", note that `(-EPSILON < 0.0) == (-EPSILON < -0.0)`, and that's the point - it doesn't matter which zero it is, you can work with both of them the same way using this approach. (Finding the equal is just doing `not` on the above, and fairly simple).

Comment: `if (r >= |0.0 - EPSILON|)` This is unnecessary; `if (r >= EPSILON)` suffices.

Answer (score 12):

On some older systems (i.e. pre-IEE754) you may find equality checks against 0 fail for negative-0:

```
if (a == 0.0) // when a==-0.0, fails
```

you can work around this by adding 0.0 to a value before the comparison:

```
if ((a+0.0) == 0.0) // when a == -0.0, succeeds
```

---

I would caution, however, that combinations of hardware/software that really require this are *quite* unusual. The last time I had to do it was on a Control Data mainframe. Even there, it only arose under somewhat unusual circumstances: the Fortran compiler allowed negative zeros to be generated, and knew to compensate for them in comparisons. The Pascal compiler generated code to turn negative zeros into normal zeros as part of a computation.

Therefore, if you wrote a routine in Fortran and called it from Pascal, you could run into this problem, and prevent it as above by adding 0.0 before doing a comparison.

I'm gonna put pretty good odds that your problem doesn't really stem from comparisons with negative zero though. All reasonably modern hardware of which I'm aware handles this entirely automatically, so software never has to consider it at all.

Comment: Considering the OP's new more detailed example, I think you won that bet :-)

Comment: `if (a == 0.0) // when a==-0.0, fails` where? This violates IEEE 754.

Comment: @RJFalconer: As stated in the answer, the specific example in question was a Control Data mainframe (which predated IEEE 754 by several years). As my closing sentence said, this is handled automatically on "all reasonably modern hardware". Next time you might want to actually read the answer before down-voting.

Comment: Actually that's not quite what you state in your answer. You merely say that's the last time you had to do it. If you clarify your opening I'll remove the down vote.

Comment: @RJFalconer: I'm confused about what you think needs clarification. As to what I said, here's a CnP: " All reasonably modern hardware of which I'm aware handles this entirely automatically, so software never has to consider it at all."

Comment: To save comment spam I'll make an edit; please revert/update as you see fit.

Comment: Does adding 0.0 make the calculation notably slower? I've ran into a situation where -0 is returned when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 7):

The OP mentions `std::signbit` in his question, but it should be in an answer to be found quickly, so here it is:

This works since C++11 to distinguish between `-0.0` and `+0.0`:

```
#include <cmath>
std::signbit(x) // true iif sign bit of x is set i.e. x is negative
```

[std::signbit on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit)

Comment: To get the sign as -1 or 1, you need:
    auto sgn = [](double x) {
        return 1 - 2 * std::signbit(x);
    };

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you meant something like `if (r2==-0.0)`. Nonetheless, both negative 0 and positive 0 will compare equal. For all intents and purposes there's no difference between the two. You probably don't need to have a special case for negative 0. Your comparison `r >= 0` [*should* be true](http://ideone.com/8YbxY7) for either negative or positive 0.

Comment: I assumed the same but when testing I've run into cases when `r` is `-0.0` and the return statement doesn't act the same as it does for `0.0`. Weird, I know.

Comment: @Justin Do you have an example of that? Sounds strange.

Comment: But what makes you think `r` is "negative zero", rather than just some other negative number close to zero? If it's those debug outputs, try using `%g` instead of `%f`...

Comment: interesting. `%g` does produce different results. `r=-2.78269e-07` instead of `-0.000000`.

Comment: @Justin Then it's just a very small negative number. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double const x = -2.78269e-07;

    printf( "printf: x=%f\n", x );
    cout << "cout: x=" << x << endl;
}
```

With result (using Visual C++ 11.0):

```
[D:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp
foo.cpp

[D:\dev\test]
> foo
printf: x=-0.000000
cout: x=-2.78269e-007

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

This seems awfully similar to the mysterious result in the question.

It's my considered opinion that it quacks like the question's result, looks like the question's result *and* waddles like the question's result.

So, I believe that the not shown computation code produced the value `2.78269e-007`.

---

So, in conclusion,  it was apparently only the described behavior, about “negative zero” comparing unequal to zero, that was non-standard. In reality there is apparently no negative zero, just *a very small negative value*. Which with the given output format is presented as all zero digits with a minus sign in front.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a very small negative number that the console couldn't print it for you
You can try checking for it depending on your precision so you can replace it with a **pure zero**.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << (abs(value) < 0.0000005f ? 0 : value);
```

**Notice** how I added 7 places to the floating precision as I specified with `std::setprecision()`.

It depends on how accurately you want to print your floats/double.

Answer (score 0):

These will do the trick - but the compiler might optimize it out:

if (-v == 0.0)
v = 0.0;

if (v == -0.0)
v = 0.0;

So I thinks this is better:

```
if (v < DBL_EPSILON && v > -DBL_EPSILON)
    v = 0.0;
```

Comment: Note that there are many numbers that have absolute values less than `DBL_EPSILON` that are quite definitely *not* zero. That constant is the smallest value that can be added to `1` such that the result is not (still) 1.

Comment: should be `if (std::nextafter(0., -1.) < v && v < std::nextafter(0., 1.))`